# SSRS - find, scroll

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

SSRS has a find button on the toolbar. Hosting an SSRS report control in ASP.NET and when you use the find and it finds something at the bottom of the report, it doesn't scroll down automatically. Wondering if anyone has seen or done anything to make the scroll happen on find in the SSRS report?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are running the most updated version of SSRS. I recall in the past some of these controls were broken and fixed in a later release.
2. Ensure Javascript is enabled on your browser and add the site to your trusted list. If I recall correctly, IE has strict default permissions for intranet sites. If that doesn't work, see if it works in another browser and that will help you determine if it is browser related.
3. Make sure you have all CSS and javascript resources on your server. My reports contain a reference to: "assets/js/app-ffc8de72-74aa-48f8-bf1d-634ee0627bca-bundle.min.js".

I can confirm this feature is working in SSRS 2016.